# Does solidity support overloading of constructors?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I know that different functions can have the same name but take different parameters.  For instance, the truffle assert library has equalities and inequalities on lots of datatypes.  But I just tried to do the same for a constructor and got a compiler complaint.  I'd like to be able to say

`contract Foo {
    function Foo (uint onearg) {
        return Foo(onearg, 2);
     }
    function Foo (uint onearg, uint secondarg) {
        ... do the real work ...
     }
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, from the [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#creating-contracts), "A constructor is optional. Only one constructor is allowed, and this means overloading is not supported."

Comment: Thanks.  I looked for that, and failed.  Unfortunate.  I wonder if there are plans to allow it.